# When does this inequality hold: $h^2/\beta^2 \le \beta \exp(h/ \beta)$?

Tags: inequality

If $h<0$ and $\beta >0$. When we can have the next inequality
$$\frac{h^2}{\beta^2} \le \beta \cdot\exp(h/ \beta)$$

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to solve 
$$
\frac{h^2}{\beta^2} \le \beta \cdot\exp(\frac h \beta)
$$
for $h<0,\beta>0$ in a general algebraic way in the sense that you get anything like
$$
f(h)\le g(\beta)
$$
with $f,g$ are some suitable functions. Of course you could try to use some numerical methods, for example [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bh%5E2%7D%7B%5Cbeta%5E2%7D+%5Cle+%5Cbeta+%5Ccdot%5Cexp(h%2F+%5Cbeta)) produces a nice plot.

However, to get an intuition it might be the best to go for three cases
$$
|h|>|\beta|,\,|h|<|\beta|,\,|h|=|\beta|
$$
You'll find for each case solutions but for the third case, when we have $|h|=|\beta|,h<0,\beta>0$, we can indeed construct a solution since
$$
|h|=|\beta|\implies\frac {h^2}{\beta^2}=1,\frac {h}{\beta}=-1
$$
which gives us
$$
\frac{h^2}{\beta^2} \le \beta \cdot\exp(\frac h \beta)\iff1\leq\beta\frac1 e\iff e\leq\beta
$$
but that's about it.